# Strange Output results

Tags: javascript

i was training my self in javascript programming and having trouble to understand the output of 2 results, for example:

```
1) var num = 1;
var result = num++ * 10 +1;
console.log(result);
```

At fist i thought that the output would be '21', since it was increment 1 value to num and the mutplications was always the first to calculate, but than i notice the result was 11, than i imagine that was because num was immutable (not sure).

Than appears me this function:

```
function A(param){
        var m = param;
        m = m+10;
        return m;
    }
    console.log(A(10));
```

And the result of the function was 20.

This confused me a lot and i cant understand what is going wrong, can someone explain me what just happened?

Comment: [Increment and decrement operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue is that `num++` returns the value of `num` before it is incremented. Actually your expression looks like: `1 * 10 + 1`.

You should use `++num`, this statement will return the value of `num` after it would be incremented:

```
var result = ++num * 10 + 1; // 21
```

Answer (score 0):

`num` is not immutable.

The output of `m++` is `m` (the value before it was incremented).  If you want the value after the increment, use `++m`.

```
var num = 1;
console.log(++num);
```

gives `2`, whereas

```
var num = 1;
console.log(num++);
```

gives `1`.